# The tallest possible lattice?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

Let O be a complete discrete valuation ring and G a finite group.  Recall that a finitely generated O-free OG-module $M$ such that the traces of the invertible endomorphisms of $M$ generate a strictly larger ideal of O than the traces of the non-invertible endomorphisms is called a *Knoerr lattice* (or virtually irreducible lattice).  As Knoerr showed, such lattices are absolutely indecomposable.

If $M$ is a Knoerr lattice in a block of defect $d$, and $p^a$ is the order of a Sylow $p$-subgroup, then the *height* of $M$ is defined to be $h$, where $p^{a-d+h}$ is the exact power of $p$ dividing the rank of $M$.

It is relatively easy to see that the height of $M$ is bounded by $d$- and is equal to $d$ if and only if $d=0$.  It seems in general (according to the literature) that positive height lattices have height at most $d/2$.  This is shown to hold for abelian $p$-groups in a paper by Geline and Robinson: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869312002232#

My question is: does the bound $h\leq d-2$ hold for all Knoerr lattices $M$ for all groups?  I am told (but don't quite see why!) that if $S$ is the source of $M$, then the height of $S$ equals the height of $M$, so the question can be reduced to $p$-groups (and thus we are left with non-abelian $p$-groups by the result of Geline and Robinson).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: As Geoff Robinson mentions below, the bound is actually at least $d-2$, not $d/2$.

Comment: I don't think the $d/2$ bound holds in general. In $2$-blocks with semidihedral defect groups of order $2^{d},$ and with a "maximal fusion system", there are irreducible characters of height $d-2,$ which exceeds $d/2$ if $d > 4.$ Was that a typo on your part?

Comment: Unfortunately not- I just hadn't seen any examples where that bound was exceeding.  Do you know what the ramification degree of the field (over $\mathbb{Q}_p$) is for these characters of height $d-2$?

Comment: Not sure. Would have to check- probably at least two.